# gluUnProject ray picking(opengl/c++/glut)

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, mouse, glut

I am trying to see if I can click on a 3D drawn object, using the mouse, in a 3D world. I understood that I have to use gluUnProject so I tried it out in the following way:

Firstly I have a function that gets the x,y coordinates from the mouse(the window coordinates), and tries to transform them into real world coordinates:

```
void project(int x_cursor, int y_cursor){

GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble projection[16];
GLfloat winX,winY;
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

// obtain the Z position (not world coordinates but in range 0 - 1)
GLfloat z_cursor;
winX = (float)x_cursor;
 winY = (float)viewport[3]-(float)y_cursor;
glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z_cursor);

// obtain the world coordinates

gluUnProject(winX, winY, z_cursor, modelview, projection, viewport, &x, &y, &z);
}
```

Then I have the mouse callback function:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x_cursor, int y_cursor){
if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
{
    mouse_x=x_cursor;
    mouse_y=y_cursor;

 project(mouse_x,mouse_y);

     cout<<x<<" "<<"Printed out variable x"<<endl;
 cout<<y<<" "<<"Printed out variable y"<<endl;
 cout<<z<<" "<<"Printed out variable z"<<endl;

 /**for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) { 
if ((enemies[i]!=NULL)&&(enemies[i]->getTranslation().x > x - 1 &&     enemies[i]->getTranslation().x < x + 1) 
        && (enemies[i]->getTranslation().z > z - 1 && enemies[i]->getTranslation().z < z + 1)
        && (enemies[i]->getTranslation().y > y - 1 && enemies[i]->getTranslation().y < y + 1)) {

        running=false;
            }
    }**/
}
```

}

For the moment I am just printing out the coordinates x,y,z, but in the commented code you can see what I intend to do with them: verify if a drawn object is in the immediate vecinity of the spot where I clicked the mouse.

Lastly I added the glutMouseFunc(mouse); line in the main() function, and it compiles ok, but judging by the result of the prints it doesn't indicate the correct values.

I would like to add the fact that I have a moving camera;by this I mean I can change the glulookat parameters, using keyboard input. Could you please look at my code and maybe show me where I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

[EDIT] It only seems to work when I set the camera like: gluLookAt(-35, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 1);

[EDIT2] Also if I move the position of the camera, and then return it in the initial position(where it worked), it doesn't work anymore.

Solved. The above code is ok. The problem was I was adding glPushMatrix(); and glPopMatrix(); before and after drawing the objects in the scene. The question can be closed.

Comment: You need to fire a ray from eye_pos (from gluLookAt) to the x,y,z it give you and they find intersections with the bounding box of your monsters